# Max height of 16,384px for headless Chrome screenshots?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, centos, screenshot

No matter what I try, the maximum height of a full-page screenshot with headless Chrome 60 (and 59) is 16,348px.

It is not a memory issue. There are no segfaults and no, for example, `FATAL:memory_linux.cc(35) Out of memory.` messages. None. Capturing screenshots are "successful". Changing the screenshot format - PNG or JPEG - has no affect.

The screenshot width can vary, but the height of the saved screenshot is always limited to 16,348px. Example,

> 1600x16384, 1200x16384, 2400x16384, etc.

I'm taking upscaled screenshots with this minimal code ([full source](https://github.com/schnerd/chrome-headless-screenshots/blob/master/index.js)):

```
const upscale = 2;

const viewportWidth = 1200;
const viewportHeight = 800;

....

// Set up viewport resolution, etc.
const deviceMetrics = {
    width: viewportWidth,
    height: viewportHeight,
    deviceScaleFactor: 0,
    mobile: false,
    fitWindow: false,
    scale: 1    // Relative to the upscale
};
await Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride(deviceMetrics);
await Emulation.setVisibleSize({width: viewportWidth, height: viewportHeight});
await Emulation.setPageScaleFactor({pageScaleFactor: upscale});

// Navigate to target page
await Page.navigate({url});

const {root: {nodeId: documentNodeId}} = await DOM.getDocument();
const {nodeId: bodyNodeId} = await DOM.querySelector({
    selector: 'body',
    nodeId: documentNodeId,
});
const {model: {height}} = await DOM.getBoxModel({nodeId: bodyNodeId});

// Upscale the dimensions for full page
await Emulation.setVisibleSize({width: Math.round(viewportWidth * upscale), height: Math.round(height * upscale)});

// This forceViewport call ensures that content outside the viewport is
// rendered, otherwise it shows up as grey. Possibly a bug?
await Emulation.forceViewport({x: 0, y: 0, scale: upscale});

const screenshot = await Page.captureScreenshot({format});
const buffer = new Buffer(screenshot.data, 'base64');

file.writeFile(outFile, buffer, 'base64', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Exception while saving screenshot:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Screenshot saved');
    }
    client.close();
});
```

I was unable to find any useful [Chrome switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) either. Is this a hardcoded limit of Chrome? 16384 is a suspicious number (2^14 = 16,384). How can this height be increased?

Comment: From what I read it's a limitation of the [Skia library](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=339725). But, that post is from 2014. [This post](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/headless-dev/qcvOjVUZ-WQ) might also be informative.

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of Chromium as documented in this bug

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=770769&desc=2